# How to integrate Hand Controlle HC1 in my car simulator game

Tags: unity-game-engine

I m building a car simulator game using Unity. For the input I m using Logitheck steering wheel G29. Now I need to use Hand Controller to accelerate or break.
This is my Hand Controller
Hand Controller HC1
[Link](https://www.3drap.it/product/hand-controller-throttle-and-brake-gaming-is-possible/)

Now I can I interpect his input ? This device is recognize by my windows 10 system, but if I try to start the game with this device I cannot accelerate or break the car.

I configured this in my InputController of Unity:
[image]

And in my IRDSPlayerControls.cs file I write these lines of code:

```
if (Input.anyKey)
        {
            foreach (KeyCode kcode in Enum.GetValues(typeof(KeyCode)))
            {
                Debug.Log("Joystick pressed " + kcode);
            }
        }
        Debug.Log("Input debug acc: " + Input.GetAxis("Vertical3"));
        Debug.Log("Input debug frenata: " + Input.GetAxis("Vertical4"));
```

In Console of Unity, I can display this:

```
Input debug acc: -1
Input debug frenata: -1
```

Comment: Does it work with other games?

Comment: I know if this device is supported from "Forza Horizon 5" game

Answer (score 2):

You can detect a specific button on a specific joystick `joystick 1 button 0, joystick 1 button 1, joystick 2 button 0…`

or a specific button on any joystick   `joystick button 0, joystick button 1, joystick button 2…`

Check out [Input Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-InputManager.html)

I can explain this step by step here but it wont be as good as some tutorials online. I recommend [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZbIjeWZz60) as a good tutorial to do this.

### UPDATE:

I think your hand controller give analog values and the acceleration/brake buttons are not actually buttons but they are analog joy sticks and have a range of values.

to check this use [Input.GetJoystickNames](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetJoystickNames.html) :

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Prints a joystick name if movement is detected.

    void Update()
    {
        // requires you to set up axes "Joy0X" - "Joy3X" and "Joy0Y" - "Joy3Y" in the Input Manager
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if (Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxis("Joy" + i + "X")) > 0.2 ||
                Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxis("Joy" + i + "Y")) > 0.2)
            {
                Debug.Log(Input.GetJoystickNames()[i] + " is moved");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please avoid link only answers.  The web is not stable, without the links, this is a non-answer.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to first check if those inputs are being received with:

```
if (Input.anyKey)
 {
         foreach(KeyCode kcode in Enum.GetValues(typeof(KeyCode)))
         {
              Debug.Log(kcode);
         }
 }
```

This way you can know if the game is recognizing the keycodes of your controller, and if it does, which names are assigned to them.
Once you got this, you only need to check keycodes as an usual keyboard!

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, I will check and let you know asap

Comment: With your code I m not able to display button pressed. I just edit my question

Answer (score 0):

Not every joystick, steer etc. is mapping it's inputs to the same axis.

There is a unity forum about that topic (and other related problems). And I found that there are some unity plugins, that could probably solve your problem:

- https://github.com/speps/XInputDotNet
- https://github.com/JISyed/Unity-XboxCtrlrInput

There are some programs that you can use to list all input axis and see which one you are currently affecting. I used one of them but don't remember the name of it. It might help you to see to which axis your break and throttle are mapped to.
Some of them also allow you to remap then, if this is what you want.